# Changing the anchor point of the scrollviewer (WPF)

Tags: wpf, alignment, scrollbar, anchor, scrollviewer

I am trying to do something a little bit specific, and I can't seem to find if it is even possible. So I thought I would lay down the question here.

What I'm looking for is a way to change the anchor point of the scrollviewer from the top to the bottom (however you look at it). I'll explain what I mean.
By default when the control contained in your scrollviewer gets taller, so will your vertical scrollbar scollableheight.
But what happens is, the vertical scrollbar will stay at the same scrolloffset **from the top**, while what I want is that the vertical scrollbar keeps it's position relative to the bottom. The reason I want this behaviour is because I am creating a list that the user can expand more of by scrolling to the top. but then when I add the new items it looks like the scrollviewer scrolls up to the newly added items. (although it is actually the content the is pushed down) So if the scrollviewer would have the vertical scrollbar anchored to the bottom, the visible part of the content would stays at the same position to the user because the distance from that part to the bottom didn't change.

I hope you can understand what I'm trying to do.

I allready found one way of doing this, but it is not the desired option to me.

Option 1) Apply a Scaletransform of -1 in the Y-axis to the scrollviewer to flip it upside down. Then apply another ScaleTransform of -1 in the Y-axis to the content of the scrollviewer to make the content right side up.
But the problem with this technique is that for one, when you scroll using your mousewheel the scrollviewer scrolls inverted as normal. And second, I'm using 2 scaletransformations just to change the behaviour of the scrollviewer, and not even for eye candy. So that seems a bit excessive to me.

Option 2) anyone?

Comment: Forget all that. Use a regular `ListBox` and change the `SelectedItem` every time you add a new Item. Then use `ListBox.ScrollIntoView(ListBox.SelectedItem)` and you're good to go. Don't try to reinvent the wheel. It's already been invented.

Comment: @leigero: not exactly the warm welcome I expected from stackoverflow. I am simply looking for a bit more advanced help, then a regular google search gets you...

Comment: @Highcore: Actually my scrollviewer contains a wrappanel that in turn contains multiple copies of a usercontrol. So I don't think a listbox can help me here. (or am I wrong?) Also I'm looking for the cleanest solution possible, I want to avoid the flicker and dirtyness of rescrolling back to our original position.

Comment: @user3077410 yes you're wrong. A UI element that shows items and allows selection of one or more of them is a `ListBox`. Regardless of it's visual appearance. In WPF you choose UI elements according to their functionality, not their visual appearance. You can still use a `WrapPanel` inside the `ListBox.ItemsPanelTemplate`

Comment: @user3077410 I wasn't trying to be rude, nor roll out the welcome wagon. I was presented this question and asked to provide feedback. You got a dry and objective review. I didn't down-vote the question, but in the event that you got down-voted people often fail to explain why, so I wanted to include that just in case.

Comment: I had a partial success using the ScrollChanged event, and inside there scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset( scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + e.ExtentHeightChange );   It doesn't line up perfectly but at least it stays at the bottom when my ScrollViewer's content grows and shrinks